# How to update the UI system in unity after changing a triangle in code

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I am trying to write a real time Line Graph Renderer using the UI system in Unity 2019. Meaning I need to change the data on the fly and have the graph update.

What i have found is that OnPopulateMesh is not being called unless i Physically update the properties via the inspector, if i do it via the Update method in the rubbish test example below, the Triangle drawn on the screen does not update at all (despite the values in the inspector updating), the triangle will jump to it's new position, if i update something else on the script via the inspector.

Anyone know what i should use to update this via c#?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TriangleRenderer : Graphic
{
    public List<Vector3> Verts = new List<Vector3>
    {
        new Vector3(-100, -100, 0),
        new Vector3(-100, 100, 0),
        new Vector3(100, 100, 0)
    };

    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
        vh.Clear();

        if(Verts.Count != 0 && Verts.Count % 3 == 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < Verts.Count; i+=3)
            {
                vh.AddVert(Verts[i], Color.white, Vector2.zero);
                vh.AddVert(Verts[i+1], Color.white, Vector2.up);
                vh.AddVert(Verts[i+2], Color.white, Vector2.one);
                vh.AddTriangle(i, i + 1, i + 2);
            }
        }
    }

    bool flipped = false;
    private float speed = 2f;
    private Vector3 orig;
    private float freedom = 100f;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        orig = Verts[2];   
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (flipped)
        {
            Verts[2] = new Vector3(Verts[2].x + Time.deltaTime * speed, Verts[2].y, Verts[2].z);
        }
        else
        {
            Verts[2] = new Vector3(Verts[2].x - Time.deltaTime * speed, Verts[2].y, Verts[2].z);
        }

        if (Verts[2].x > orig.x + freedom || Verts[2].x < orig.x - freedom)
        {
            flipped = !flipped;
            Verts[2] = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(Verts[2].x, orig.x - freedom, orig.x + freedom), Verts[2].y, Verts[2].z);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I should also note that I tried the following in the update loop (to no effect):         using (VertexHelper vh = new VertexHelper())
        {
            this.OnPopulateMesh(vh);
        }

Comment: Browsing the API documentation, [Rebuild](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.html#UnityEngine_UI_Graphic_Rebuild_UnityEngine_UI_CanvasUpdate_), [SetVerticesDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.html#UnityEngine_UI_Graphic_SetVerticesDirty), and [UpdateGeometry](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.html#UnityEngine_UI_Graphic_UpdateGeometry) all look like promising leads. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks! Not sure how i missed those. looks like SetVerticesDirty is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: If you find it works for you, be sure to post your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory's response, I was able to get this working using the SetVerticesDirty() method from the UnityEngine.UI.Graphic class.

So to get the above horrible code udating the triangles in realtime, i could simply modify the update method as follows:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (flipped)
    {
        Verts[2] = new Vector3(Verts[2].x + Time.deltaTime * speed, Verts[2].y, Verts[2].z);
    }
    else
    {
        Verts[2] = new Vector3(Verts[2].x - Time.deltaTime * speed, Verts[2].y, Verts[2].z);
    }

    if (Verts[2].x > orig.x + freedom || Verts[2].x < orig.x - freedom)
    {
        flipped = !flipped;
        Verts[2] = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(Verts[2].x, orig.x - freedom, orig.x + freedom), Verts[2].y, Verts[2].z);
    }
    SetVerticesDirty();
}
```